# libgfortran.so.4 in Fedora 28

Tags: r, fedora

I'm running Fedora 28, and now R is throwing the error below. I'm now unable to update (or even load) certain packages.

libgfortran.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I believe the problem is that Fedora now comes with a newer version of the FORTRAN compiler, which is required by these R packages.

In the following directory, I have a library libgfortran.so. I assume this is the file it's looking for but is most likely too up to date?
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/libgfortran.so

'dnf info libgfortran' tells me I'm running version 8.1.1 of libgfortran (so GCC 8). Whereas I believe libgfortran.so.4 comes from GCC 7.

I tried 'dnf downgrade libgfortran', but it was just an earlier version of GCC 8.

To be honest, I'm completely lost with a way to solve this. I need R, but at the moment it's useless. Apart from waiting for the R package devs to update their Fortran compilers, is there another way I can fix this?

Comment: How did you install R? Did you compile R yourself?

Comment: Get **libgfortran.so.4** → `libgfortran4-7.2.1-1.1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm` http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/libgfortran4-7.2.1-1.1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm ... Install : `# dnf install Downloads/libgfortran4-7.2.1-1.1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: That fixed it, installing the older version of libgfortran. Sorry, I should have realised, I was thinking for some reason that I couldn't have two versions of the same compiler on the one computer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, as Knud pointed out, is to install the older version of libgfortran alongside the newer one in Fedora.

Get libgfortran.so.4 → libgfortran4-7.2.1-1.1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm

Link here:
[mirror.centos.org/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/…](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/libgfortran4-7.2.1-1.1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm)

Install : `sudo dnf install ~/Downloads/libgfortran4-7.2.1-1.1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm`
or if it fails with dnf try
`sudo yum install ~/Downloads/libgfortran4-7.2.1-1.1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: or use `sudo yum install ~/Downloads/libgfortran4-7.2.1-1.1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm` if `dnf` fails

Comment: The proved link to mirror.centos.org no longer works.

Comment: This link could be an alternative
https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=mingw64(libgfortran-4.dll)

Answer (score 3):

The link provided by [marius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116518/marius) is not working, kind of inactive active.

**Fedora 32, CentOS 8**

Install:

```
sudo dnf install https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.8.2003/os/x86_64/Packages/libgfortran4-8.3.1-2.1.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

**RPM resource libgfortran4**:

https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libgfortran.so.4()(64bit)